# Integrating Golang CLI tool in my Python project

Tags: python, go, command-line-interface, owasp

How easy is it to integrate a CLI tool written in different language into my Python project.

For example, I have an API endpoint. When it receives a request with a query (e.g. domain name), I want to run OWASP’s AMASS tool - written in Go.

As I have no experience in this, I want to know **if this is possible?**
Any tutorials or resources I can read to learn how to do it.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Comment: this is very late reply but yes I think subprocess is the answer